# Simplifying XAML code

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am still very angry about how needlessly complicated are styles, templates and similar things in WPF. I am trying to figure out how to avoid duplicate XAML code like this:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1">
  <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
    <xcdg:TableflowView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
      <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
        <DataTemplate>
          <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
    </xcdg:TableflowView>
  </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>  

  </xcdg:DataGridControl>
  <xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
      <xcdg:TableflowView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
        <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
          <DataTemplate>
            <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
      </xcdg:TableflowView>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
  </xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

I want to have something like this:

```
<ViewSettings>
<xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
  <xcdg:TableflowView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
    <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
      <DataTemplate>
        <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
  </xcdg:TableflowView>
</xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
</ViewSettings>  

<xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
  ViewSettings
<xcdg:DataGridControl/>
<xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
  ViewSettings
<xcdg:DataGridControl/>
```

Comment: Create a default Style for DataGridControl?

Comment: Just something, that will avoid writing this duplicate code for these two DataGridControls in one Window. It can be defined either globally with key, or locally in Window resources.

Comment: I don't really see what the problem is, there are lots of ways to reuse xaml, styles (they can be based on another styles, can also be done explicitly and implicitly), usercontrols which could have common xaml in them. Attached properties if you wanted to reuse some customs properties. Dictionaries you can define templates etc with keys and them use them. Lots of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom style for **xcdg:DataGridControl** which set the View property, store it in a FrameworkElement resource dictionary and refer to it with StaticResource.

Here it is stored in the parent grid resource dictionary.

```
<Grid>   
     <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="datagrid_style" TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataGridControl}" >
            <Setter Property="View">
                <Setter.Value>
                   <xcdg:TableflowView UseDefaultHeadersFooters="False">
                      <xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
                         <DataTemplate>
                            <xcdg:ColumnManagerRow/>
                         </DataTemplate>
                      </xcdg:TableflowView.FixedHeaders>
                   </xcdg:TableflowView>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
        </Style>
     <Grid.Resources> 

     <xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource datagrid_style}" />
     <xcdg:DataGridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource datagrid_style}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but Xceed DataGridControl can not have same view definition for multiple grids, so it is needed to add x:Shared="False" to style definition.